# Creating a table out of text files in a folder with specific formatting

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a program which will take all the .txt files in a folder and append them into one large table. The folder which contains the files has them ordered numerical from least to greatest, and that is also how I would like my final result to be since I am trying to use the table for a color map. The issue is that it must always add both columns of the first file and then only the second column of every file after that. This is because the first column is the frequency which is the same for every file and only the amplitude changes.

The files are structured as follows:

```
File1.txt = File1[0] File1[1]
             freq      amp
             freq      amp
              .         .
              .         .
             freq      amp
```

I would like my end result to look like:

```
Table.txt = File1[0] File1[1] File2[1] File3[1] ... File(n)[1]
             freq      amp      amp      amp           amp
             freq      amp      amp      amp           amp
             freq      amp      amp      amp           amp
```

Apologies in advance if there is any abuse of notation, I am learning python as I go along with my research.

So my code thus far is

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import os, glob, _thread, re, time, argparse

## Get path
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = '')
parser.add_argument('directory', nargs = '?', action = 'store',
                default = os.curdir, help = 'Directory containing data')
results = parser.parse_args()
path = results.directory

## Regex for files
matchThis = '(\d+)\.(\d)([a-z][A-Z])\.(txt)'

## Coulmn from which data is used, MuMax = 1 : Daq = varies on output 
col = 1

########

def main():
    #Get file names of all files in current folder
    datafilesName = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))
    #Sort the list according to numbers in "matchThis"
    datafilesName.sort(key = numkeys)

    outputM = open('..\output_matrix.txt','wb')
    first = True

    M = []

    for file in datafilesName:
            print(file)
            data = np.loadtxt(file, usecols = (0,col), unpack = True)


            newData = np.array(data[1])
            if first:
                    M.append(data[0])
                    M.append(newData)
            else:
                    M.append(newData)
            first = False

    np.savetxt(outputM, np.transpose(M))
    outputM.close()

    return

########

def numkeys(text):
    return [item for item in re.findall(matchThis,text) ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your question (problem statement) is a bit vague for me. Do you have any code that demonstrates how you want to start or approach this problem?

Comment: I just edited the question to include my code, sorry about not placing it in the first place.

Comment: cool, no worries thanks for updating with code. what in it works/doesn't work to accomplish your goal? it seems it should almost be complete.

Comment: @downshift I fixed my issue, the float conversion in my numkeys definition was the error I kept getting. No more late night coding for me :)

Comment: It turns out that my code doesn't work as intended, it does not keep the files organized and i am not sure why.

Comment: well, if you can more show how it's not working as expected, maybe we can help

Comment: what about the files are not keeping organized? Do you mean the final table does not sort the file names and contents in ascending order?

Comment: The final table is not in ascending order, at least the order I would like. It organized them by only looking at their decimal value. so maybe the sorting is off?

So they are appended as follows: 0 10 100 102.5 105 107.5 ... 12.5 120 122.5 ...

My intentions were that it would go from 0 to 180 in increments of 2.5.

Comment: Oh, because it looks like those values are being read as strings, hence the sorting by each digit, and not by value. Try checking the datatype of the values in the table to ensure they are floats so they can be sorted by decimal value

Comment: The internal values of the table are floats but the file name (which is what it should sort) give me an error when I try to convert them to floats.

    line 60, in <listcomp>
    return [float(item) for item in re.findall(matchThis,text) ]
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Comment: ah ok, maybe inspect the tuple with `print([type(item[0]), type(item[1]) for item in re.findall(matchThis,text)][0])` -- might have to adjust my syntax, to get something like `<type 'float'>` or `<type 'str'>`